How do I run the same GitHub Cypress workflow on frontend repository?
I have been looking for an answer everywhere, it is the first time for me setting up a workflow for another repository. So, I have separate repository for my Cypress tests and a workflow which works good on PUSH in this repo. What I want is running the whole test suite from the repository on frontend repository on pull request.
Here what I have and it works good but in Cypress repository:
    name: E2E on Chrome
on: push
jobs:
  test:
    name: Cypress run
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    strategy:
      # when one test fails, DO NOT cancel the other
      # containers, because this will kill Cypress processes
      # leaving Cypress Cloud hanging ...
      # https://github.com/cypress-io/github-action/issues/48
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        # run 3 copies of the current job in parallel
        containers: [1, 2, 3]
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      # because of "record" and "parallel" parameters
      # these containers will load balance all found tests among themselves
      - name: Cypress run
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v6
        with:
          record: true
          parallel: true
          group: 'e2e tests'
          browser: chrome
        env:
          # pass the Cypress Cloud record key as an environment variable
          CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY: ${{ secrets.CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY }}
          # Recommended: pass the GitHub token lets this action correctly
          # determine the unique run id necessary to re-run the checks
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

Can you give me a step by step how do I setup pipelines in github for the frontend?
